# XSLT - Remove element based on another element child value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to remove element based on another element child value.
This is example xml file:

```
<Information>
    <List>
        <Element ID="101278">
            <MetaData>
                <Value AttributeID="DisplayOrNo">no</Value>
              </MetaData>
        </Element>
        <Element ID="101277">
            <MetaData>
                <Value AttributeID="DisplayOrNo">yes</Value>
              </MetaData>
        </Element>
    </List>
<Products>
    <Product ID="3333">
      <Name>test_name</Name>
      <Values>
        <Value ElementID="101278">test_text</Value>
        <Value ElementID="101277">test_text</Value>
      </Values>
    </Product>
  </Products>
</Information>
```

I want remove element Value inside Product/Values if value of element List/Element/MetaData/Value is no.
Value element will have information about ID attribute of Element. This should probably help with matching them.

I expect something like this:

```
<Information>
    <List>
        <Element ID="101278">
            <MetaData>
                <Value AttributeID="DisplayOrNo">no</Value>
              </MetaData>
        </Element>
        <Element ID="101277">
            <MetaData>
                <Value AttributeID="DisplayOrNo">yes</Value>
              </MetaData>
        </Element>
    </List>
<Products>
    <Product ID="3333">
      <Name>test_name</Name>
      <Values>
        <Value ElementID="101277">test_text</Value>
      </Values>
    </Product>
  </Products>
</Information>
```

Do you think it will be possible to also after matching and removing Value elements, totally remove whole List inside Information ? Or do i have to make second XSLT to remove List ?
Should look like here:

```
<Information>
<Products>
    <Product ID="3333">
      <Name>test_name</Name>
      <Values>
        <Value ElementID="101277">test_text</Value>
      </Values>
    </Product>
  </Products>
</Information>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do this in XSLT 2.0 (or even XSLT 1.0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="elem-by-id" match="Element[MetaData/Value[@AttributeID='DisplayOrNo']='no']" use="@ID" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="List"/>

<xsl:template match="Value[key('elem-by-id', @ElementID)]"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most currently supported versions of XSLT processors support XSLT 3.0, the current version, or XSLT 1.0. So assuming you use e.g. a currently supported version of Saxon for XSLT 2, it will also support XSLT 3 accumulators:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="display" streamable="yes"/>

  <xsl:accumulator name="display" as="xs:string*" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="List/Element[@ID]/MetaData/Value[@AttributeID = 'DisplayOrNo']/text()[. = 'yes']" select="$value, string(ancestor::Element/@ID)"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
  
  <xsl:template match="List"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="Products/Product/Values/Value[not(@ElementID = accumulator-before('display'))]"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```